# For loop not iterating in Mailchimp

Tags: python, api, mailchimp

So, I'm trying to get every sent to list from the Mailchimp API. I've made this code to elaborate a list of it to later generate a join and get both the list and the campaign name and not the campaign id only:

```
 try:
  client = MailchimpMarketing.Client()
  client.set_config({
    "api_key": "xxxx",
    "server": "xxx"
  })

  response_id = client.campaigns.list(count=1000)
  df_full = pd.json_normalize(response_id['campaigns'])
  df_id = df_full['id']
  df_id = df_id.values.tolist()
  df_id_camp_name = df_full[['id','settings.subject_line']]
  #display(df_id)



except ApiClientError as error:
  print("Error: {}".format(error.text))
```

This part of the script gets the ID for each campaign and each campaign name.

```
for id in df_id:
  try:
   client = MailchimpMarketing.Client()
   client.set_config({
     "api_key": "xxxxx",
     "server": "xxxx"
   })

  
   response_open = client.reports.get_campaign_recipients(id, count=1000)
   df_open = pd.json_normalize(response_open['sent_to'])
   df_open_full = df_open.append(df_open) 
  
  except ApiClientError as error:
   print("Error: {}".format(error.text))

df_open_full.to_excel("campaign_reports_mailchimp.xlsx")
```

And this last piece, takes the ID from the generated list and allegedly runs the code for each ID. Problem is that the generated excel only brings one campaign and doesn't iterates for the rest of the IDs.
I know that the API has a limit count but it should move to the next ID once the cap reaches since it restarts the for loop itself.

What could be wrong in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the exception handler being run? Otherwise, I can't see any reason why it wouldn't iterate.

Comment: Add print statements to the code so you see what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some details about the print itself of each piece of code:

First block:

```
['076ff218d1', '08f16d1014', '0abfd11f5d', '0bb98a7839', '0bca92ee08', '0be206c6ac', '0e048c0d08', '0e28d0feee', '138271cade', '14bf2cd33b', '15c9ce24ed', '17b5302f30', '19721c1e8a', '1d8cc5c1da', '1f5362e2f4', '205480a063', '225bc2469b', '22f286dfbe', '26dec9723b', '2846539c87', '296e9c24f5', '2aa089aa37', '2f819130ff', '352d7913ae', '3a563ffb24', '3a73d3e5b6', '3c83f64170', '3d87a76763', '3e6a903948', '404ab63b91', '4198b629c6', '424b941199', '42e948e744', '46a29946a3', '48e56d7481', '4a0a55eb73', '4caf7e8cc1', '4e3c90946f', '53c8e8a8de', '54600382dd', '55a8915fb8', '5a28843185', '5d575f0de8', '60488c9e4b', '612b068a5b', '6161c05556', '61f5edcefa', '623c98757a', '689ae72a35', '68a8b5dadd', '6b3797ea1a', '6b606e78fb', '6dd276171d', '6ead2584c8', '6f99e38311', '70632fe9e7', '709b6fd5f8', '72a1b314b4', '74b92a828e', '75bdf2a3fe', '75cce79a85', '7687c62b55', '79e63229a8', '79f67ec7b8', '7f9dddc6c0', '807a75418e', '8548a5f525', '8602aa9cdd', '87c4bd5a07', '8bb822eeb3', '8ec05b63fa', '8f0c7d0cce', '900018816a', '924976c731', '933a2af282', '95a170d72c', '977beb5616', '98f8ee7fed', '99dbbc746c', '9a01a1b518', 'a1ad97ae8e', 'a4aa98b22b', 'a7c535a5b9', 'a978bab42b', 'ab13c82454', 'ab7c015390', 'acdc57b754', 'ad66024938', 'ae8464e351', 'ae95f63873', 'aeba2b962a', 'af0d9fe032', 'af6a4efe07', 'b19c553cd1', 'b5f4196035', 'b7a9ced6c8', 'b7eab10f0f', 'b80b52c97b', 'bd56fd7a6d', 'bdbb60aec7', 'c142343cfd', 'c2eb923ada', 'c407b9856d', 'c4636be5a1', 'c6145916ae', 'c84e39f8ef', 'c937f5876e', 'c97497c3e4', 'ca468b0942', 'cf2a040b92', 'cf81c2ac84', 'd006696585', 'd1b57067d2', 'd67915da02', 'd687b97dec', 'd698158ac5', 'd78cb47ccd', 'da0e85a878', 'dfc6a9bffc', 'dfe8e851e8', 'e08ce9ad82', 'e33f24fdcb', 'e4c478afb4', 'e8e3faaf5a', 'ebee2d5079', 'ecafe77954', 'ef1dae3863', 'f045de38f4', 'fa07a15c0e', 'fa3936c575', 'fa4def8ca1', 'fc1f708dc7', 'fe4f89c745']
```

Second block of code:

[Extract of code display(df)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4jO3.png)

Also adding an error displayed in the loop because I'm using pd.append instead of pd.concatenate (since I don't have any other df to concatenate with)

> FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be
> removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.